# On "have had been" in a theoretical past

Tags: tense, past-perfect

When talking about a theoretical situation in the past - in the present case this sentence: "It is because those people (theoretical) would not have had been (action) - is it correct to use "have had been"?

Answer (score 1):

There may be some dialects that use this, but it's not grammatical in any standard English that I am aware of.

Auxiliary *have* can be followed by the past participle of the main verb:

> They have seen him.
>
> They have had dinner.

or by *been* (ppt of "be") for continuous or passive:

> They have been seeing him.
>
> The have been seen by him.

but not by any other auxiliary

Comment: Then what tense should I use? "Would not had been"?

Comment: @folopolo: that's not grammatical. Modals such as _would_ must be followed by the base form of the next verb, even if it is an auxiliary. _would not have been_.